# Spring Security - Redirect to custom login page without going through controller

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I am currently using Spring Boot + Spring Security to develop a simple website that need user to login to access it. I have created my own custom static login page under **resources/templates1/bruceLogin1.html**. Any unathenticated access to my website to first be redirected to the login page URL which is http://localhost:8080/templates1/bruceLogin1.html

Note: that I am NOT creating any controller for this login URL, hence I am expecting the bruceLogin1.html to be accessed directly bypassing controller. Because i directly allow access to this html page without going thru controller, I assume no view resolver (e.g thymleaf) is required.

I open my browser, and enter http://localhost:8080/blablabl, and browser redirect me to http://localhost:8080/templates1/bruceLogin1.html , but sadly, i got error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jan 11 12:40:37 SGT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Below is my configuration,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityCatalogApplication  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityCatalogApplication.class, args);
    }



    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

             http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/templates1/bruceLogin1.html")
             .permitAll();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think instead of putting under resources/template1 folder, i will just put the custom login page into either resources/static or resources/public folder. 
Then configure as shown below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

             http
             .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/bruceLogin1.html")
             .permitAll();
        }
    }
```

Open browser and access any URL, you will be redirected to http://localhost:8080/bruceLogin1.html.  And thats it!
Note that this does not require any controller nor view resolver.